# What is "platformBuildVersionCode" in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest

For what reason `platformBuildVersionCode` and `platformBuildVersionName` are mentioned in Android Manifest file? Already `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` also mentioned.

```
android:versionCode="8762015"android:versionName="0.3.6" package="com.android.app"
platformBuildVersionCode="19" platformBuildVersionName="4.4.2"
```

I need reason for mentioning that.

Comment: When you create an Android app u have to decide what is the minimum version and the actual version of the android SDK, for example i could work in icecream but give support to honeycomb. The word platformBuildVersionName that u see in the code is auto generated by the SDK

Comment: You can check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39645128/5515371

Comment: @EnriqueQuero What does **auto generated by the SDK** mean in this context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's platformBuildVersionCode and platformBuildVersionName in Extracted Apk's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291397/whats-platformbuildversioncode-and-platformbuildversionname-in-extracted-apks)