# What's platformBuildVersionCode and platformBuildVersionName in Extracted Apk's

Tags: android, android-manifest, apktool

Extracted an Apk using APKTool getting the `manifest.xml` like this,

```
<manifest xmlns:"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:versionCode="31" 
android:versionName="3.1" 
package="xxx.xxx.xxx" 
platformBuildVersionCode="22" 
platformBuildVersionName="5.1.1-1819727">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Need to know what's `platformBuildVersionCode` and `platformBuildVersionName`

Already Checked this,[What is "platformBuildVersionCode" in AndroidManifest.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32500911/5515371)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a long analysis,
i got solution,`platformBuildVersionCode` is `targetSDKVersion` and `platformBuildVersionName` is version name of `targetSDK`(like Android 6.0) which are mentioned in `build.gradle`.

Comment: this just copyes my answer.

Answer (score 12):

`platformBuildVersionCode` is added by a compiler, and means a version of `targetSDK`
`platformBuildVersionName` is a readable version name of `targetSDK` version.

Comment: then what's this,<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" /> mentioned already

Comment: Why is there **platformBuildVersionCode="24"**  and **<uses-sdk
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />** in the same Manifest file?

Answer (score 11):

`platformBuildVersionCode` overrides and takes precedence over `android:compileSdkVersion` in the merged AndroidManifest.  This is evidenced in the following android git commit:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ad2d07d