# Is there any way to stop Qt 5.9 from replacing values of versionCode and versionName in apk's AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, qt, android-manifest, qt5.9, qt5.12

Values of platformBuildVersionCode (versionCode) and platformBuildVersionName (versionName) are always replaced with the values of targetSDKVersion and targetSDK in apk's AndroidManifest file.

I have tried below ways.

1. Modified these fields from build.gradle
2. Tried to build from terminal and changed value of these fields from terminal.
3. https://forum.qt.io/topic/52250/how-can-i-stop-qtcreator-from-overwriting-my-androidmanifest-xml
4. This issue is seen only for Qt 5.9. I tested on Qt 5.9.4 and Qt 5.9.8.
   Works perfectly fine on Qt 5.12.2.

Ref: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ad2d07d

[What's platformBuildVersionCode and platformBuildVersionName in Extracted Apk's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291397/whats-platformbuildversioncode-and-platformbuildversionname-in-extracted-apks/39291595)

These options are not working for me. I want to  keep these values as it is in apk's manifest also with Qt 5.9.8.

Comment: It is not an answer, just some food for thought. Qt 5.9 support will end in 5 months (May 2020). At this point you will have 2 other LTS versions of Qt (5.12 and 5.15). If you cannot find a quick and easy solution for your problem, since you will likely have to move from Qt 5.9 in the near future, it might be worth moving to a newer Qt version that does not have this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can not go with Qt 5.12 as it is having some different issues which is not acceptable for me. Waiting for next LTS i.e. Qt 5.15.

Comment: Do you have any idea when next LTS version is planned by Qt?

Comment: Qt 5.15 is scheduled for May 2020. See https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.15_Release 
You can also check the Releasing mailing list, there is a recap of the current state weekly: https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/releasing/

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this useful information. It will help me to make a decision.

Comment: Just a quick note. The Qt Company will stop making LTS releases for the open source edition: https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-offering-changes-2020